# Objective-C Find first matching regular expression in string

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have a task with regular expressions. I have a list of `NSRegularExpression` objects with different patterns. Also I have a `NSString` object to define a source. I need to find **which** regular expression (from the given list) matches for the **BEGINNING** of source.

Is there a way to do it with **Objective-C**?

**For example:**

Expressions patterns

1. `[a-z]`
2. `[A-Z]`
3. `[1-9]`

source

`Hello32`

Result

**Expression no 2** fits for the beginning of source, because of letter `H`.

Comment: Define "BEGINNING of source." If I understood correctly, you can try one by one each `NSRegularExpression`, get the matchRange, and if the matchRange pass the test, add it to a "success" list.

Comment: Updated my question with example.

Comment: You could prepend `^` to each pattern to force matching from the start

Comment: @Mariano No. Consider the pattern `^[A-Z]`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe It matches a capital letter from the beggining of the string, which I believe is what the OP wants

Comment: @Mariano Yes, but simply prepending `^` to this pattern makes it not match. I'm saying, there are valid patterns (that match at the beginning of the string) that can be broken by prepending `^`

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe None of the examples provided. Either way, prepending `^(?:` and appending `)` works for all use cases

Comment: @Mariano Why don't you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try them out?

```
NSString *testString = @"Hello";

NSArray *patterns = @[
    @"[a-z]",
    @"[A-Z]",
    @"[1-9]",
];

for (NSString *pattern in patterns) {
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                           options:0
                                                                             error:NULL];
    BOOL matchAtStart = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:testString
                                                 options:0
                                                   range:(NSRange){0, testString.length}].location == 0;
    NSLog(@"'%@': %@", pattern, @(matchAtStart));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend `\A(?:` and append `)` to each pattern to force them to match at the beggining of the string. The patterns provided as example would become:

```
\A(?:[a-z])
\A(?:[A-Z])
\A(?:[1-9])
```

- `\A` is an anchor to the beggining of the string (behaves exactly like `^` when the `Multiline` flag is not set).